Run rosdep command in a apptainer/singularity .def file
I am trying to define a .def file to build an apptainer/singularity image to run TurtleBot4 simulation. I have to run a rosdep command to install some dependencies but I got the following error when I execute apptainer build ros_gazebo_rosdep.sif ros_gazebo_rosdep.def:
+ rosdep install --from-path src -yi --rosdistro humble given path 'src' does not exist FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 1
But I'm running the build command in the same repo where the src is located.
This is my .def file:
From: osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full

%post

    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y lsb-release wget gnupg

    wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list > /dev/null
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y ignition-fortress 
    
  apt install -y python3-colcon-common-extensions
    apt install -y qml-module-qtquick-extras
    
    rosdep update -y

    rosdep install --from-path src -yi --rosdistro humble
          

